# When does Firebase Analytics track my users?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm working on a new version of my app that implements a new online mode, the old offline mode however will still be accessible. I chose to use Firestore as my database and I just noticed that Google tracks on what VC my users are without me having to set up anything regarding analytics.

While calls to Firebase just happen if the user chose to use the online mode I still use the same VC for both modes and that means that even if the user is in offline mode Firebase gets imported. My question is now when it is that google tracks the user on the VC. So if the user just gets tracked if the VC makes a call, or as soon as I import Firebase into the VC class. Or stated differently if I will just see the users using online mode in the analytics dashboard, or all my users.

(sorry for my english :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics for Firebase automatically tracks screen views in your app. You can [temporarily disable analytics in your app](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#temporarily_disable_collection_2) and then reenable in your code, or you can [permanently disable it](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#permanently_deactivate_collection_2).